# AWS Amplify - Cognito, how to know that my user has right to do some actions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-amplify

I have a React App and the backend has been built with AWS Amplify, it works perfect with CRUD operations.

But I would like to know how to select permissions for pay user or free user.

For example, my app will have 3 months free, but after that time, all the users will have to pay 12$, the user that dont pay, just will be able to perform read actions after the 3th month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never done that, but my approach would be the following:

- allow the operation create, update and delete only for the group trial and premium (https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/directives#static-group-authorization)
- every new user is assigned to the group trial
- a scheduled lambda will check if a user is assigned longer than 3 month to the group trial and if yes than remove the user from the group trial

Comment: I'm not pretty sure if the lambda fuction is the best choice to do this, but I was looking for the static group auth concept, I didn't know and I will follow this way. 

I need to think more about how to detect if a user has more than 3 months and how to change it from one group to another. 

Thanks.